# Recommendation using Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, recommender-system

I am trying to write my own recommender system. I have data set of user-item rating matrix. But I do not have profile information about either items or users. I already built pure CF using cosine and Pearson. I am trying to build a recommender system using the random forest. I read some paper but those are the random forest in model-based recommender systems. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does CF mean? In any case, recommendation data is typically very sparse (many many more movies exist than any single Netflix customer has watched) and RF typically struggles when working on sparse data. An alternative might be something like a factorization machine, which was explicitly developed as a recommendation system which also is amenable to sparse data.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial CF means collaborative filtering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you calculate cosine similarity Random Forests can be used for unsupervised learning. These unsupervised Random Forests output similarity matrices based on proximity. The only caveat is that the Random Forest similarity is based on whole data, i.e. it's not pairwise calculated, you must give it the whole data for it to learn the similarity, as it's based on the number of times two given observations ended on the same leaf in the trees. In other words, this means that you'd need to recalculate the whole proximity matrix for all data every time a new observation is added.

To read about unsupervised Random Forests, I recommend [this small description on Leo Breiman and Adele Cutler site](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#unsup) (the inventors of Random Forests).

Even wikipedia includes a section on [unsupervised learning with random forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#Unsupervised_learning_with_random_forests).

Comment: This answers the question of how to adapt random forest to finding similar items in the sense that they are the items which often inhabit the same terminal nodes of the trees, but it's not clear how one goes from having that similarity matrix to a recommender system. Perhaps you could expand upon that?

Comment: @GeneralAbrial Sorry, I never ventured in that area. I just tackled the issue (OP said he knows how to build a recommender based on similarity; my answer tells him how to get similarity from Random Forests, but I don't actually know how to actually build a recommender out of a similarity measure). Sounds interesting though.

Answer (score -2):

RF cannot be used for memory-based recommender system.

Memory-based methods use similarity metrics(1). Similarity metrics (e.g. cosine similarity) are unsupervised and are just executing a user defined rule.

RF is not a similarity metric. It is a supervised learning model.

(1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering#Memory-based

Comment: Except that Random Forest can be used to generate similarity matrices in unsupervised fashion.